# Group by Regression in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, group-by, regression

I am very new to TensorFlow - so please bear with me if this is a trivial question.

I'm coding in Python+TensorFlow. I have a dataframe with the following structure -

Y | X_1 | X_2 | ... | X_p | Grp

where Y is the continuous response, X_1 through X_p are features, and Grp is a categorical value indicating group. I want to fit a separate linear regression of Y on (X_1,...,X_p)for each Grp and save the weights/coefficients. I do not want to use the out of the shelf tf.estimator.LinearRegressor. Instead I want to go the loss function-optimizer-session.run() route.

The relevant tutorial pages on internet talk about linear regression but not per group. I would appreciate any suggestions. I am thinking to do this -

For each g in Grps : 
 1. Call the optimizer by passing the data for Group g as the placeholders.
 2. Get the estimated weights (for Group g) and save them in a dataframe : Grp | weights

Another approach that sounds reasonable is to have separate graphs for each group and kick them all together using various "sessions".

Are these reasonable and feasible in TF? Which one is easier or are there better approaches?

Thank you,
Sai

Comment: It look like a homework. Could you tell as what you have tried so far? [follow here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Mitiku, thank you for your comment. Let me assure you that it is not a homework! I am asking for a reasonable approach to take. I have listed two approaches I'm thinking but since I'm new to TF, I'm searching (and asking experts like yourself) to see if there are already existing solutions as the problem I described seems to occur naturally. Thanks for sharing the link. I don't have an error in my code ...I'm just seeking advice.